# (Proof Verification) : ACT for Integrals

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to kindly request your assistance in looking at my work and giving me a feedback on my work if its missing something or wrong.

Question :  that if $\int_{a}^{\infty}|f(x)| d x$ converges then $\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x) d x$ converges moreover
$$
\left|\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x) d x\right| \leq \int_{a}^{\infty}|f(x)| d x
$$

My proof : First, we note that $f(x)\in\mathcal{R}\implies|f(x)|\in\mathcal{R}$. Moreover, $f(x)\leq|f(x)|$ and thus $0\leq\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)\;\text{d}x\leq\int_{a}^{\infty}|f(x)|\;\text{d}x$, since $\int_{a}^{\infty}|f(x)|\;\text{d}x$ converges then by comparison test we have $\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)\;\text{d}x$ converges. Since $f(x)\in\mathcal{R}$, then we define $\mathcal{P}$ to be a partition of $[a,b]$, $\mathcal{P}=\{\underbrace{x_{1}}_{a},x_{2},\cdots,\underbrace{x_{3}}_{b}\}$ where $b>a$ such that $\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\;\text{d}x$ exists due to convergence of the integral. Thus, by definition we have that $L(\mathcal{P},f)=U(\mathcal{P},f)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}M_{i}x$. Therefore :
\begin{align*}
&\left|\int_{a}^{b} f(x) d x\right|=\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}M_{i}x\right|\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n}|M_{i}|x=\int_{a}^{b} |f(x)| d x \\
\implies&\lim_{b\to\infty}\left|\int_{a}^{b} f(x) d x\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}M_{i}x\right|\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|M_{i}|x=\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b} |f(x)| d x \\
\implies&\left|\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x) d x\right| \leq \int_{a}^{\infty}|f(x)| d x
\end{align*}

Comment: The second part makes no sense.  You are confusing upper and lower Darboux integrals  with the upper and lower Darboux sums.

Comment: Please do not delete your question just after it is answered.  This is disrespectful to the person who took the time to answer your question, and disrespectful to future readers who might be helped by the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misusing the  comparison test which applies when $0 \leqslant f(x) \leqslant g(x)$. Then convergence of $\int_a^\infty g(x) \, dx $ implies convergence of $\int_a^\infty f(x) \, dx $ .  You don't have $f$ nonnegative as an assumption here. You write $0 \leqslant \int_a^\infty f(x) \, dx$.  Even if the integral converges (which you have not yet established)  it might be negative.

(1) To prove convergence of the integral of $f$ we can apply the Cauchy criterion since
$$\left|\int_{c_1}^{c_2} f(x) \, dx \right| \leqslant \int_{c_1}^{c_2} |f(x)| \, dx < \epsilon$$

(2) To prove the inequality note that

$$-\int_a^b |f(x)| \, dx \leqslant \int_a^b f(x) \, dx \leqslant \int_a^b |f(x)| \, dx,$$

and, hence,

$$-\int_a^\infty |f(x)| \, dx \leqslant \lim_{b \to \infty}\int_a^b f(x) \, dx  = \int_a^\infty f(x) \, dx \leqslant\int_a^\infty |f(x)| \, dx,$$

which implies

$$\left|\int_a^\infty f(x) \, dx\right| \leqslant \int_a^\infty |f(x)| \, dx$$

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, may I ask is there an alternative way that does not rely on Cauchy Criterion? @RRL